# Скачивание видео через CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp, cloudflare, webclient

Есть много прямых ссылок на mp4 файлы с одного сайта.
Нужно скачать их все в определенные пути на комп.
Проблема в защите Cloudflare на этом сайте.
В итоге WebClient просто скачивает страницу js проверки от Cloudflare.
Пробовал подсунуть куки - не получилось.
Сами видео в хроме открываются.

Подключил CefSharp к программе - в нем ссылки с видео тоже открываются.
Как скачать их теперь через CefSharp?
Хотелось бы простой пример как с WebClient:

```
myWebClient = new WebClient();
Uri url_file = new Uri(url);
myWebClient.DownloadFile(url_file, @"E:\1.mp4");
```

Comment: Этот вопрос здесь весьма часто задается. Поищите NuGet библиотеку, которая вам поможет с обходом защиты. Браузер совсем необязательно использовать. А чтобы скачать файл браузером, выполните в нем JS скрипт.

Comment: `Пробовал подсунуть куки` Чтобы проходить через CF нужно не только куки подсовывать, а еще как минимум юзерагент в точности такой же каким брали куки. И переходите на HttpClient.

Comment: Тут это обсуждалось: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500088/curl-load-a-site-with-cloudflare-protection , попробуйте сначала через curl, если получится, то есть смысл пробовать дальше, если в точности воспроизвести запрос, но будут проблемы - мониторить различия дополнительно через Wireshark